# Merge two dataframes of different length on a specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the first dataframe "Study": this represents names of all the students in the college

```
col1
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

and my 2nd dataframe is "Student": this is a specific group of students with a particular subject

```
name   pass
C       1
F       1
B       1
```

I want to create a dataframe from the above 2 dataframes which looks something like this:

dataframe3:

```
col1 value
A      False
B      True
C      True
D      False
E      False
F      True
```

This represents students B, C, and F have value 1 in "Student" dataframe and rest all are absent.

I tried doing this using the merge method in pandas, something like this:

```
df3 = Study.merge(Student, left_on="col1", right_on="name", how="left")
```

but it results in:

```
col1     name    pass
A        nan     nan
B        B       1
C        C       1
D        nan     nan
E        nan     nan
F        F       1
```

To get the dataframe3 shown above - I can process this by deleting the column name and maybe replace nan by false and 1 by True, but is there any other way to do this more nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if `df1['col1']` is in `df2['name']`:

```
df3 = df1.assign(value=df1['col1'].isin(df2['name']))
df3
```

Output:

```
  col1  value
0    A  False
1    B   True
2    C   True
3    D  False
4    E  False
5    F   True
```

Answer (score 0):

If your 2nd dataframe "Student" does not just contain all Pass values 1 (can be 0), you can also do:

```
df_merge = Study.merge(Student, left_on='col1', right_on='name', how='left')
df_merge['value'] = df_merge['pass'].eq(1)
df_merge = df_merge.drop(['name', 'pass'], axis=1)
```

Result:

```
print(df_merge)

  col1  value
0    A  False
1    B   True
2    C   True
3    D  False
4    E  False
5    F   True
```

Answer (score 0):

Take only the required columns after merger i.e. `col1` and `pass`, and fill `NaN` values by `False`

```py
df3=Study.merge(Student, left_on="col1", right_on="name", how="left")[['col1', 'pass']].fillna(False)
```

Now just convert the pass column to `boolean` type

```py
df3['pass'] = df3['pass'].astype(bool)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
df3
  col1   pass
0    A  False
1    B   True
2    C   True
3    D  False
4    E  False
5    F   True
```

You can rename the columns if you want to..